# CERN ROOT exporting data to plain text

Tags: export, analysis, root-framework

So I have tried and tried to follow similar questions asked like [this one](https://root.cern.ch/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=7376), but to no success.

It's really simple - I have some .root files and can see the histograms in ROOT but want to export the data as a .txt or similar to be able to analyse it in other programs.

Comment: Maybe this comment is a bit too late. Anyways - in principle it is possible, but depends on the object (histogram: TH1, TH2 or TGraph....) you are using. In case of a TGraph you can simply get arrays for x and y (and also the errors) using TGraph::GetX() or TGraph::GetY(), also see [TGraph](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTGraph.html). For histograms data is already binned, i.e. discretized into bins. You can loop over bins and get their mean and content ([link](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html)). For higher dimensions use nested loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is working example. Reads in a root file with three branches, named TS, ns, and nserr.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TFile.h"
#include "TTree.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void dumpTreeTotxt(){
  TFile *f=new TFile("TS0.root"); // opens the root file
  TTree *tr=(TTree*)f->Get("tree"); // creates the TTree object
  tr->Scan(); // prints the content on the screen

  float a,b,c; // create variables of the same type as the branches you want to access

  tr->SetBranchAddress("TS",&a); // for all the TTree branches you need this
  tr->SetBranchAddress("ns",&b);
  tr->SetBranchAddress("nserr",&c);

  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "TS ns nserr\n";

  for (int i=0;i<tr->GetEntries();i++){
    // loop over the tree
    tr->GetEntry(i);
    cout << a << " " << b << " "<< c << endl; //print to the screen
    myfile << a << " " << b << " "<< c<<"\n"; //write to file
  }
  myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: What if the tree has no branches and just leaf/data nodes? How would the line tr->SetBranchAddress("TS",&a); be modified in that case?