# Root Cern Export Data: export a specific data type

Tags: c++, root-framework

as i wrote in the title, i'm trying to export data from a tree, i've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970124/cern-root-exporting-data-to-plain-text).  It's work but i've problem when i try to export a specific branch. The [Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViTtU.png) for the Tree, when i try to export the branch named "ADCVal" there is a crash. I think the problem is that "ADCVal" is a vector so i have to extract every element. How can i modify the code and associate to a variable every element of the branch.
I know it might seem like a simple question but my c++/root knowledge are really poor. Thank all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may want to read this [guide to asking a question well](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly how to submit a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point you can use the `MakeClass` method, this writes the code for you:

```
root org.root
root [0] 
Attaching file org.root as _file0...
(TFile *) 0x2670460
root [1] .ls
TFile**     org.root
 TFile*     org.root
  KEY: TTree    SomeTree    SomeTree
root [2] SomeTree->MakeClass("removeme")
Info in <TTreePlayer::MakeClass>: Files: removeme.h and removeme.C generated from TTree: B02DD
(Int_t) 0
root [3]
```

You can then have a look in removeme.h to see how to use `SetBranchAddress` with an array. It boils down to

```
Float_t         ADCVal[10];
tr->SetBranchAddress("ADCVal", ADCVal);
```

and then you can access `ADCVal[0]`, `ADCVal[1]`, ... after calling `tr->GetEntry(i);`